# Swagger failure to generate nested schema by automatic generation

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I'm trying to use Swagger annotations to generate a schema for a Java class that represents a Bhagavad Gita verse. Here's the class definition:

```java
package org.projectsanatan.restsanatan.books;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.ArraySchema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Schema(name = "Bhagavad Gita Verse", description = "Verse schema for Bhagavad Gita")
public class BhagavadGitaVerse {

    @SerializedName(value="chapter_id")
    @Schema(name = "chapter_id", description = "The chapter ID of the verse")
    private int chapterId;

    @SerializedName(value="verse_number")
    @Schema(name = "verse_number", description = "The verse number")
    private int verseNumber;

    @SerializedName(value="language")
    @Schema(name = "language", description = "Language of the verse")
    private String language = "";

    @SerializedName(value="author")
    @Schema(name = "author", description = "Author of the verse", nullable = true)
    private String author = "";

    @SerializedName(value="verse")
    @Schema(name = "verse", description = "The verse text")
    private String verse = "";

    @SerializedName(value="transliteration")
    @Schema(name = "transliteration", description = "The transliteration of the verse if available", nullable = true)
    private String verseTransliteration = "";

    @SerializedName(value="word_meanings")
    @ArraySchema(arraySchema = @Schema(
            description = "List of word-meaning pairs",
            implementation = WordMeaningPair.class
    ),
            schema = @Schema(
                    description = "A single word-meaning pair",
                    implementation = WordMeaningPair.class
            ))
    private List<WordMeaningPair> wordMeanings = new ArrayList<>();

    public BhagavadGitaVerse(int chapterId, int verseNumber) {
        this.setChapterId(chapterId);
        this.setVerseNumber(verseNumber);
    }

    public int getChapterId() {
        return chapterId;
    }

    public void setChapterId(int chapterId) {
        this.chapterId = chapterId;
    }

    public int getVerseNumber() {
        return verseNumber;
    }

    public void setVerseNumber(int verseNumber) {
        this.verseNumber = verseNumber;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getVerse() {
        return verse;
    }

    public void setVerse(String verse) {
        this.verse = verse;
    }

    public String getVerseTransliteration() {
        return verseTransliteration;
    }

    public void setVerseTransliteration(String verseTransliteration) {
        this.verseTransliteration = verseTransliteration;
    }

    public List<WordMeaningPair> getWordMeanings() {
        return wordMeanings;
    }

    public void setWordMeanings(List<WordMeaningPair> wordMeanings) {
        this.wordMeanings = wordMeanings;
    }

    public void addWordMeaning(String key, String value) {
        this.wordMeanings.add(new WordMeaningPair(key, value));
    }

    public void addWordMeaning(WordMeaningPair wm) {
        this.wordMeanings.add(wm);
    }

    public void removeWordMeaning(WordMeaningPair wm) {
        this.wordMeanings.remove(wm);
    }

    private static class WordMeaningPair {

        @SerializedName(value="word")
        @Schema(description = "The word")
        private String word;

        @SerializedName(value="meaning")
        @Schema(description = "The meaning")
        private String meaning;

        public WordMeaningPair() {

        }

        public WordMeaningPair(String word, String meaning) {
            this.setWord(word);
            this.setMeaning(meaning);
        }

        public String getWord() {
            return word;
        }

        public void setWord(String word) {
            this.word = word;
        }

        public String getMeaning() {
            return meaning;
        }

        public void setMeaning(String meaning) {
            this.meaning = meaning;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the class has properties that correspond to the fields in a Bhagavad Gita verse, including a list of WordMeaningPair objects that represent the meanings of the words in the verse.

I want to use Swagger annotations to generate a schema for this class, but I'm having a problem with the wordMeanings property. When I run the Swagger code generation tool, it creates a separate schema component for WordMeaningPair, instead of including it as a property inside the BhagavadGitaVerse schema. Here's the generated YAML:

```yaml
    Bhagavad Gita Verse:
      type: object
      properties:
        chapter_id:
          type: integer
          description: The chapter ID of the verse
          format: int32
        verse_number:
          type: integer
          description: The verse number
          format: int32
        language:
          type: string
          description: Language of the verse
        author:
          type: string
          description: Author of the verse
          nullable: true
        verse:
          type: string
          description: The verse text
        transliteration:
          type: string
          description: The transliteration of the verse if available
          nullable: true
        wordMeanings:
          type: array
          description: List of word-meaning pairs
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/WordMeaningPair'
      description: Verse schema for Bhagavad Gita
    WordMeaningPair:
      type: object
      properties:
        word:
          type: string
          description: The word
        meaning:
          type: string
          description: The meaning
      description: A single word-meaning pair
```

As you can see, the generated YAML has a definition for a schema just for having it in one schema reference. I want it in the single BhagavadGitaVerse schema because its going to be used in only in that component. My generated YAML should look something like this:

```yaml
    BgVerse:
      type: object
      properties:
        chapter_id:
          type: integer
        verse_number:
          type: integer
        language:
          type: string
        verse:
          type: string
        transliteration:
          type: string
        word_meanings:
          type: array
          items:
            type: object
            properties:
              word:
                type: string
              meaning:
                type: string
```

I have tried changing a lot of the annotations and looked up the docs and other sources as well, but couldn't find anything relevant.